# Django-notification invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: django, django-notification

I'm using `django-notification` to create notifications. based on [it's documention](https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications) I putted:

```
url(r'^inbox/notifications/', include(notifications.urls, namespace='notifications')),
```

in my `urls.py`. I generate a notification for test by using this in my views.py:

```
guy = User.objects.get(username = 'SirSaleh')
notify.send(sender=User, recipient=guy, verb='you visted the site!')
```

and I can easily get the number of unread notification in this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/inbox/notifications/api/unread_count/
```

it return `{"unread_count": 1}` as I want. but with `/api/unread_list/` I can not to get the list of notifications and I get this error:

```
ValueError at /inbox/notifications/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '<property object at 0x7fe1b56b6e08>'
```

As I beginner in using `django-notifications` any help will be appreciated.

**Full TraceBack**

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/inbox/notifications/api/unread_list/
>
> Django Version: 2.0.2 Python Version: 3.5.2 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'django.contrib.sites',  'django.forms',  'rest_framework', 
>   'allauth',  'allauth.account',  'allauth.socialaccount',  'guardian', 
>   'axes',  'django_otp',  'django_otp.plugins.otp_static', 
>   'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp',  'two_factor',  'invitations', 
>   'avatar',  'imagekit',  'import_export',  'djmoney',  'captcha', 
>   'dal',  'dal_select2',  'widget_tweaks',  'braces',  'django_tables2',
>   'phonenumber_field',  'hitcount',  'el_pagination', 
>   'maintenance_mode',  'notifications',  'mathfilters', 
>   'myproject_web',  'Order',  'PhotoGallery',  'Search',  'Social', 
>   'UserAccount',  'UserAuthentication',  'UserAuthorization', 
>   'UserProfile'] Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', 
>   'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware', 
>   'maintenance_mode.middleware.MaintenanceModeMiddleware']
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "/home/saleh/Projects/myproject_web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     35.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/home/saleh/Projects/myproject_web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/home/saleh/Projects/myproject_web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/saleh/Projects/myproject_web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notifications/views.py"
>   in live_unread_notification_list
>     164.         if n.actor:
>
> File
>   "/home/saleh/Projects/myproject_web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/fields.py"
>   in **get**
>     253.                 rel_obj = ct.get_object_for_this_type(pk=pk_val)
>
> File
>   "/home/saleh/Projects/myproject_web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py"
>   in get_object_for_this_type
>     169.         return self.model_class()._base_manager.using(self._state.db).get(**kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/saleh/Projects/myproject_web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py"
>   in get
>     394.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/saleh/Projects/myproject_web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py"
>   in filter
>     836.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/saleh/Projects/myproject_web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py"
>   in _filter_or_exclude
>     854.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
>
> File
>   "/home/saleh/Projects/myproject_web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py"
>   in add_q
>     1253.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
>
> File
>   "/home/saleh/Projects/myproject_web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py"
>   in _add_q
>     1277.                     split_subq=split_subq,
>
> File
>   "/home/saleh/Projects/myproject_web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py"
>   in build_filter
>     1215.         condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
>
> File
>   "/home/saleh/Projects/myproject_web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py"
>   in build_lookup
>     1085.         lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
>
> File
>   "/home/saleh/Projects/myproject_web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py"
>   in **init**
>     18.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
>
> File
>   "/home/saleh/Projects/myproject_web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py"
>   in get_prep_lookup
>     68.             return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
>
> File
>   "/home/saleh/Projects/myproject_web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py"
>   in get_prep_value
>     947.         return int(value)
>
> Exception Type: ValueError at /inbox/notifications/api/unread_list/
>   Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: What are
 your Python, Django, and Django-notification versions?

Comment: `python3`, `Django==2.0.2`, and `django-notifications-hq==1.4.0` @Selcuk

Comment: Do you have the full traceback?

Comment: @Cole I just added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops! It was my mistake. 
I Finally find out what was the problem. `actor_object_id` was the field of `notifications_notification` table, which `User.objects.get(username = 'SirSaleh')` saved in it. It should be `Interger` (`user_id` of actor).

So I dropped previous table changed instance to `User.objects.get(username = 'SirSaleh')` to User ID. Problem solved.

**So Why type of `actor_object_id` is CharField (varchar)? (at least I don't know)** ;))

Answer (score 1):

The actor_object_id needs to be a CharField to support UUID based primary keys.

Comment: Thanks, 
But I think at-least I think it's better with a validation on `save`.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I happen to know the answer.

In your code, you wrote:

```
guy = User.objects.get(username = 'SirSaleh')
notify.send(sender=User, recipient=guy, verb='you visted the site!')
```

You express that you want `guy` to be your sender However, in `notify.send`, you marked the sender as a generic `User` object, not `guy`.

So, change your code to:

```
guy = User.objects.get(username = 'SirSaleh')
notify.send(sender=guy, recipient=guy, verb='you visted the site!')
```

Notifications will take the user object `guy`, extrapolate the ID and store it in the database accordingly.